# Java: How to determine the concrete type of an abstract type?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have a method

```
public static Set<MyClass> doSomething(Set<MyClass> oldSet) {

  //I don't necessarily want this to be a HashSet
  Set<MyClass> newSet = new HashSet<MyClass>();

  //Add some things to newSet

  return newSet;
}
```

Is there any way that I can return the same concrete type as the passed in Set? (Without having to return oldSet). Unfortunately, Sets can't be cloned.

**Example**

if oldSet is a TreeSet, I would also like the returned set (newSet) to be a TreeSet.

Comment: Your question is not clear, atleast for me. Please improve

Comment: I've added an example - is that better?

Comment: Alexei's answer is perfect

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
Set<MyClass> doSomething(Set<MyClass> oldSet) {

  Set<MyClass> newSet =oldSet.getClass().newInstance();

  return newSet;
}
```

This only works if concrete class of oldSet has a constructor without parameters.

Comment: All collections should have such a constructor, according to the `Collection` JavaDoc: >>>"All general-purpose Collection implementation classes ... should provide two "standard" constructors: a void (no arguments) constructor, ... and a constructor with a single argument of type Collection, which creates a new collection with the same elements as its argument."<<<.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using reflection:

```
Class<? extends Set<MyClass>> type = oldSet.getClass();
Constructor ctor = type.getConstructor();
Set<MyClass> newSet = ctor.newInstance();
```

(from the top of my head, you'll have to add a couple of types and a ton of exception handlers).

You can also clone the set:

```
Class<? extends Set<MyClass>> type = oldSet.getClass();
Constructor ctor = type.getConstructor( Collection.class );
Set<MyClass> newSet = ctor.newInstance( oldSet );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go over the set, clone each object in the set and put it into the new set. That is assuming that MyClass is clone-able.